# mysql Update doesn't update?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out why this mysql update query doesn't actually update the mysql database!

I cannot find the reason why!

The page gets an ID from add.php file and the values related to that ID get echo-ed in the form properly but for some reason it doesn't update the mysql at all!!

could someone please let me know if I am missing something?

here is my code:

```
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {

    $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['thisID']);
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['title']);
    $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['details']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = "UPDATE pages SET title='$title',  details='$details', WHERE id='$pid'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    header("location: add.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Gather this product's full information for inserting automatically into the edit form below on page
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id='$targetID' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
    if ($productCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 

             $title = $row["title"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, that don't exist.";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

and here is the HTML form in the page:

```
<form action="pages_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" align="right">Page Tile</td>
    <td width="80%"><label>
      <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="64" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
      </label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Page Body</td>
    <td><label>
      <textarea name="details" id="details" cols="64" rows="5"><?php echo $details; ?></textarea>
      </label></td>
  </tr>      
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><label>
      <input name="thisID" type="text" value="<?php echo $targetID; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Make Changes" />
      </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you just use http://uk3.php.net/mysqli_error to work out the error?

Comment: There's an extra `,` just before the `WHERE` in your update query. Is it a typo?

Comment: @trogdor good spot! On another note, please read a little about sanitisation of data. This form is currently extremely insecure!

Comment: @trogdor, Thanks for pointing that out. I thought that would solve the issue but it didn't unfortunately...

Comment: @Alex, this is not going to be live. just need to get the functions sorted first and then I will make the script secure.

Answer (score 4):

You're *probably* getting errors from the database server and ignoring them.  [Use `mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error) to inspect the errors.

For starters, you have an extra comma in your query.  You don't need a comma before the `WHERE` clause, so change to:

```
UPDATE pages SET title='$title', details='$details' WHERE id='$pid'
```

Additionally, is the `id` column really a string?  It's more likely that it's an integer.  (Unless, of course, you made it a string.  Check the table schema to know for certain.)  If that's the case then you wouldn't want to surround the value with single-quotes.  So change to:

```
UPDATE pages SET title='$title', details='$details' WHERE id=$pid
```

There could very well be other errors.  Check the database response (as mentioned before) for errors, and check the PHP logs for errors.  You need to debug your code, don't just look at it and guess what the problems might be.

Furthermore, it's worth noting that your code is currently ***highly vulnerable*** to [SQL injection attacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  Luckily, the PHP documentation [explains the concept](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) thoroughly, and has [examples of alternatives](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: appreciate the advise. could you please let me know which part of the code is vulnerable?

Comment: You should be using [`bind_param`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of string interpolation.