# Update MySQL using HTML Form input and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have MYSQL incoming data in HTML form inputs at page opening. When I press the update button after changing the information, the update operation is successful, but the data is not updated.

```
<?php


$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$baglan = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname) or die(myslqi_error());


$place = $_POST['n_place'];
$description = $_POST['n_description'];
$latitude = $_POST['lat'];
$longitude = $_POST['long'];
$kayitliyer = $_POST['search_new_places'];
$yetkiliad = $_POST['n_yetkiliad'];
$magazaad = $_POST['n_magazaad'];
$telefon = $_POST['n_telefon'];
$yetkilitelefon = $_POST['y_telefon'];
$derece = $_POST['derece'];
$country = $_POST['country'];


$sql =  "UPDATE tbl_places SET place='$place',description='$description',lat='$latitude', lng='$longitude', kayitliyer='$kayitliyer',
yekiliad='$yetkiliad', magazaad='$magazaad', telefon='$telefon', yetkilitelefon='$yetkilitelefon', derece='$derece' WHERE place_id='$gID' ";



if (mysqli_query($baglan,$sql)) {
  echo '<br/><div class="container"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
              Kayıt Güncelleme <b>Başarılı :-)</b> <a href=javascript:history.back(-1)>Geri Dön</a>
             </div></div> ';
}else {
  echo '<br/><div class="container"><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              Güncelleme İşlemi <b>Başarız!</b> <a href=javascript:history.back(-1)>Geri Dön</a>
             </div></div>'. mysqli_error($baglan);
}



?>
```

HTML Page Form SELECT Query.Thanks for your reply. I get the value of "$ gID" from the HTML form page, where I entered the DB data with a SELECT query.UPDATE

```
  <?php
 //UPDATE ID
   $gID = $_GET["place_id"];

   include ("baglanti.php");

 $sorgu = mysqli_query($baglan,"select * from tbl_places where place_id='$gID'");


  while($goster = mysqli_fetch_array($sorgu)){
  $grupadi = $goster["place"];
  $id = $goster["place_id"];
  $desc = $goster["description"];
  $adres = $goster["kayitliyer"];
  $yetkiliad = $goster["yekiliad"];
  $magazaad = $goster["magazaad"];
  $telefon = $goster["telefon"];
  $yetkilitelefon = $goster["yetkilitelefon"];
  $derece = $goster["derece"];
  $country = $goster["country"];
  $lat =$goster["lat"];
  $long = $goster["lng"];
  }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
```

Comment: Use prepare statement to avoid sql injection

Comment: `WHERE place_id='$gID'` from where are you getting the `$gID` value?

Comment: `$gID`  is not defined

Comment: $gID not exits. for avoid SQL injection you should read -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql Update doesn't update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313836/mysql-update-doesnt-update)

Comment: share code above

Answer (score -3):

You should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for this, for security and code cleaniness. Apart from that, and without more info on where `$gID` comes from, I'd try removing the single quotes around the value it's compared to, since it probably is an integer and not a string:

```
$sql =  "... WHERE place_id=$gID";
```

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference between using `mysqli_` or `PDO_` - the real difference is using `prepared statements` vs. not using them. Prepared statements can be used with mysqli_  as well as with PDO_. So to use "PDO for security" isn't true. Its about using "prepared statements for security" - PDO and prepared statements are not the same!!! http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: PDO compels you to use prepared statements, while mysqli doesn't. That's one reason I prefer PDO and the reason I recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get the value of "$ gID" from the HTML form page, where I entered the DB data with a SELECT query.

Comment: Can you add the part of your PHP code where you get its value, please?

Comment: Why does PDO compels me to use prepared statement?

Comment: I downvoted because you're making an advice not providing an answer.

Comment: Vote as you wish, but I did provide an answer with example code.

Comment: @Miguel Still wondering where PDO compels me to use prepared statements?

Comment: If you check the API and examples of PDO, you'll see it's supposed to be used with prepared statements. You don't just throw an SQL query at it as you do (did) with mysql and friends.

Comment: @Miguel And what holds me back from doing `$conn->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE attr = $value")->fetchAll();` - Nothing. So I don't really see why it "compels" me to use prepared statements. You can write insecure statements with PDO as well, so saying "use PDO for security reason" is just simply not true at all.

Comment: Of course you can! I didn't say otherwise. But it's supposed to be used with prepared statements, it has an API for that, it compels you to use them (but it doesn't force you to).

Comment: Well, "compels" means "to force" ;) - Also `mysqli_*` can be used with prepared statements as well. So I don't really see any point of switching to PDO as long as you don't have any performance problems. For my part I always use PDO just because I know the syntax, but there's no advantage to `mysqli` in terms of security.

Comment: As I said, I prefer PDO, coding with it looks cleaner to me, and encourages (better than "compels", right?) good security practices. Use whatever you prefer, I recommend PDO.